# Jekyll/Liquid: Create custom tag/filter with parameters

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to write a custom tag for my Jekyll-based site that receives a bibtex string and replaces/removes some content.

The tag receives a bibtex string like this:

```
@article{heineman2001component,
title={Component-based software engineering},
author={Heineman, George T and Councill, William T},
journal={Putting the pieces together},
pages={5},
year={2001}
}
```

and the ruby code is the following:

```
module Jekyll
  class RenderBibTag < Liquid::Tag
   def initialize(tag_name, input, tokens)
      super
      @input = input
   end

   def render(context)
      output = (@input)#.gsub(/\bjournal\b[\w\s= \{\-\.\,\(\)]+\},/,'')
      return output;
   end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('render_bib', Jekyll::RenderBibTag)
```

Using the tag from the Jekyll template as follows works fine

```
{%render_bib bibstring %} #bibstring is the string above
```

When I try to use a Jekyll variable (e.g., page.bibtex which has the bibtex string)

```
{%render_bib page.bibtex %}
```

it does not recognise/pass the string.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use [https://github.com/inukshuk/bibtex-ruby](BibTeX library), [hook](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#hooks) it to a `:site:after-reset` to generate a jekyll collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found uses filters instead of tags

(First time answering my own question)

```
module Jekyll
  module BibFilter
    REGEXP = /\bjournal\b[\w\s= \{\-\.\,\(\)\-\:\+\'\/\..]+\},?/

    def bibFilter(bib)
      #filter text using regexp
      str = "#{bib}".gsub(REGEXP,'')
      #print filtered text
      "#{str}"
    end
 end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::BibFilter)
```